# Pandas: groupby forward fill with datetime index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, group-by, missing-data

I have a dataset that has two columns: company, and value.
It has a datetime index, which contains duplicates (on the same day, different companies have different values). The values have missing data, so I want to forward fill the missing data with the previous datapoint from the same company.

However, I can't seem to find a good way to do this without running into odd groupby errors, suggesting that I'm doing something wrong.

Toy data:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, None], 'b': [12,None,14]})
a.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2010', '2011', '2012'])  
a = a.unstack() 
a = a.reset_index().set_index('level_1') 
a.columns = ['company', 'value'] 
a.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Attempted solutions (didn't work: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`):

```
a.groupby('company').ffill() 
a.groupby('company')['value'].ffill() 
a.groupby('company').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Hacky solution (that delivers the desired result, but is obviously just an ugly workaround):

```
a['value'] = a.reset_index().groupby(
    'company').fillna(method='ffill')['value'].values
```

There is probably a simple and elegant way to do this, how is this performed in Pandas?

Answer (score 22):

One way is to use the `transform` function to fill the `value` column after group by:

```
import pandas as pd
a['value'] = a.groupby('company')['value'].transform(lambda v: v.ffill())

a
#          company  value
#level_1        
#2010-01-01      a    1.0
#2010-01-01      b   12.0
#2011-01-01      a    2.0
#2011-01-01      b   12.0
#2012-01-01      a    2.0
#2012-01-01      b   14.0
```

To compare, the original data frame looks like:

```
#            company    value
#level_1        
#2010-01-01        a      1.0
#2010-01-01        b     12.0
#2011-01-01        a      2.0
#2011-01-01        b      NaN
#2012-01-01        a      NaN
#2012-01-01        b     14.0
```

Comment: I see no diff in the results between 

```a['value'] = a.groupby('company')['value'].transform(lambda v: v.ffill())```

and
`a['value'] = a.groupby('company')['value'].ffill()`

Comment: a['value'] = a.groupby('company')['value'].ffill() is much faster

Answer (score 11):

You can add `'company'` to the index, making it unique, and do a simple `ffill` via `groupby`:

```
a = a.set_index('company', append=True)
a = a.groupby(level=1).ffill()
```

From here, you can use `reset_index` to revert the index back to the just the date, if necessary.  I'd recommend keeping `'company'` as part of the the index (or just adding it to the index to begin with), so your index remains unique:

```
a = a.reset_index(level=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

I like to use stacking and unstacking.  In this case, it requires that I append the index with `'company'`.

```
a.set_index('company', append=True).unstack().ffill() \
                                   .stack().reset_index('company')
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

*Conclusion* @Psidom's solution works best under both scenarios.

**toy data**

[image]

**bigger toy**

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
n = 10000
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n, 10),
                 pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=n, freq='H', name='Time'),
                 pd.Index(list('abcdefghij'), name='company'))

a *= np.random.choice((1, np.nan), (n, 10), p=(.6, .4))

a = a.stack(dropna=False).rename('value').reset_index('company')
```

[image]