# Is there a way in Pandas to fill down the previous value with condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as below and want to fill down the Stage of the same category based on the condition
`if Stage = "Delivered" then fill down "Delivered" to all the next rows else if Stage = "Paid" then fill down "Paid" to all the next rows`

| Category | Date | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-11-01 | Ordered |
| A | 2021-12-01 | Paid |
| A | 2022-01-01 |  |
| B | 2021-08-01 |  |
| B | 2021-09-01 | Ordered |
| B | 2021-10-01 | Paid |
| B | 2021-11-01 | Ordered |
| B | 2021-12-01 | Delivered |

The result should look like:

| Category | Date | Stage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-11-01 | Ordered |
| A | 2021-12-01 | Paid |
| A | 2022-01-01 | Paid |
| B | 2021-08-01 |  |
| B | 2021-09-01 | Ordered |
| B | 2021-10-01 | Paid |
| B | 2021-11-01 | Paid |
| B | 2021-12-01 | Delivered |

Could anyone help? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What is condition?

Comment: If condition means per groups then need [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597253/pandas-groupby-forward-fill-with-datetime-index)

Comment: @jezrael maybe you get a good solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mask` and `combine_first`:

Assuming your dataframe is already sorted by `Date` column.

```
df['Stage'] = df['Stage'].mask(~df['Stage'].isin(['Paid', 'Delivered'])) \
                         .groupby(df['Category']).ffill() \
                         .combine_first(df['Stage'])
print(df)

# Output
  Category        Date      Stage
0        A  2021-11-01    Ordered
1        A  2021-12-01       Paid
2        A  2022-01-01       Paid
3        B  2021-08-01           
4        B  2021-09-01    Ordered
5        B  2021-10-01       Paid
6        B  2021-11-01       Paid
7        B  2021-12-01  Delivered
```