# Pandas custom groupby fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataset:

```
    menu    alternative id  varA    varB    varC
1   NaN A   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN A   NaN NaN NaN
2   94  A   8.089481019 7.07639559  0.90627215
2   89  A   7.52310322  19.49894193 14.4562262
3   79  A   24.79634962 18.91163612 23.85341972
3   95  A   21.10990397 17.00630516 1.09875582
4   47  A   5.681766806 4.136047755 17.38880496
4   62  A   10.39459876 0.997853805 0.045331687
5   58  A   11.91790497 5.696799013 27.21424163
5   23  A   11.71107828 2.165751058 11.56534045
6   57  A   1.068603487 27.95362014 1.334049372
6   100 A   26.31848796 6.757305213 4.742282633
7   NaN A   NaN NaN NaN
7   NaN A   NaN NaN NaN
8   24  A   29.99608877 28.49057834 0.14073638
8   7   A   8.749041949 14.17745528 9.604565417
9   64  A   29.4316969  19.57593592 9.174503643
9   60  A   13.53995541 1.898164567 16.49089291
10  85  A   20.1394155  0.995839592 16.18638727
10  22  A   22.68625486 14.26052953 17.79707308
1   82  B   21.34428845 9.901326583 1.053134597
1   91  B   19.04689216 16.29217346 29.56962312
2   35  B   25.44168095 29.00407645 2.246459981
2   100 B   15.79687903 20.37920541 28.45071525
3   44  B   7.359501131 23.66924419 7.198215907
3   41  B   22.65272801 8.66227065  12.05186217
4   59  B   26.67565422 9.608511948 26.45016581
4   53  B   5.64870847  21.83063691 19.20105218
5   48  B   5.591317152 25.17616679 24.30522374
5   16  B   23.85069753 23.12154586 0.781450997
6   NaN B   NaN NaN NaN
6   NaN B   NaN NaN NaN
7   68  B   9.334935288 16.39114327 21.17696541
7   41  B   5.841577934 6.901223007 28.38116983
8   35  B   21.20288984 9.665414964 4.472546438
8   96  B   0.451299457 27.66880932 26.2120144
9   84  B   19.67310555 1.993071082 9.08442779
9   65  B   0.475983889 16.72261394 17.17122898
10  40  B   9.553130945 17.88616649 22.17570401
10  40  B   19.70487161 5.898428653 11.25844279
1   19  C   20.47792809 9.344376127 7.855311112
1   59  C   14.59141273 8.090534362 19.6972446
2   19  C   6.624345353 0.192145343 26.31356322
2   67  C   24.483236   6.718856437 25.75609679
3   67  C   27.6408808  24.91014602 25.90758755
3   30  C   26.52738124 10.78363589 4.873602089
4   14  C   3.776964641 21.16561036 24.03153234
4   46  C   16.53719818 23.86634958 25.61504006
5   NaN C   NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN C   NaN NaN NaN
6   58  C   28.1357636  15.89359176 0.567406646
6   28  C   0.708229201 12.20641988 0.309303591
7   17  C   4.319991082 21.29233667 3.516184987
7   8   C   24.09490443 9.507000131 14.93472971
8   85  C   19.99606403 21.61509867 0.161222766
8   5   C   6.056082264 25.35186187 5.375641692
9   24  C   19.83904205 24.54037422 11.08571464
9   13  C   4.388769239 7.928106767 4.279531285
10  78  C   13.67598922 5.3140143   15.2710129
10  13  C   12.27642791 16.04610858 1.815260029
```

As you can see here, I have some null values which I need to fill. However, I need to fill them in a somewhat custom manner. For every `id` and for every `menu` I need to fill the null values based on random selection among the same `menu`s (same menu number) in different `id`s which have non-null values.

Example. The `menu` **1** in `id` **A** has null values. I want to randomly select `menu` **1** in different `id` which has non-null values and fill them there. Let it be, `id` **B** and `menu` **1**. For `menu` **7** in `id` **A** let it be `menu` **7** in `id` **C** and etc.

It is somehow similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597253/pandas-groupby-forward-fill-with-datetime-index#38597362)  but iin my case, the filling should happen within the same "subgroups" if we can say so.

The final output should be something like this:

```
menu    alternative id  varA    varB    varC
1   82  A   21.34428845 9.901326583 1.053134597
1   91  A   19.04689216 16.29217346 29.56962312
2   94  A   8.089481019 7.07639559  0.90627215
2   89  A   7.52310322  19.49894193 14.4562262
3   79  A   24.79634962 18.91163612 23.85341972
3   95  A   21.10990397 17.00630516 1.09875582
4   47  A   5.681766806 4.136047755 17.38880496
4   62  A   10.39459876 0.997853805 0.045331687
5   58  A   11.91790497 5.696799013 27.21424163
5   23  A   11.71107828 2.165751058 11.56534045
6   57  A   1.068603487 27.95362014 1.334049372
6   100 A   26.31848796 6.757305213 4.742282633
7   17  A   4.319991082 21.29233667 3.516184987
7   8   A   24.09490443 9.507000131 14.93472971
8   24  A   29.99608877 28.49057834 0.14073638
8   7   A   8.749041949 14.17745528 9.604565417
9   64  A   29.4316969  19.57593592 9.174503643
9   60  A   13.53995541 1.898164567 16.49089291
10  85  A   20.1394155  0.995839592 16.18638727
10  22  A   22.68625486 14.26052953 17.79707308
1   82  B   21.34428845 9.901326583 1.053134597
1   91  B   19.04689216 16.29217346 29.56962312
2   35  B   25.44168095 29.00407645 2.246459981
2   100 B   15.79687903 20.37920541 28.45071525
3   44  B   7.359501131 23.66924419 7.198215907
3   41  B   22.65272801 8.66227065  12.05186217
4   59  B   26.67565422 9.608511948 26.45016581
4   53  B   5.64870847  21.83063691 19.20105218
5   48  B   5.591317152 25.17616679 24.30522374
5   16  B   23.85069753 23.12154586 0.781450997
6   57  B   1.068603487 27.95362014 1.334049372
6   100 B   26.31848796 6.757305213 4.742282633
7   68  B   9.334935288 16.39114327 21.17696541
7   41  B   5.841577934 6.901223007 28.38116983
8   35  B   21.20288984 9.665414964 4.472546438
8   96  B   0.451299457 27.66880932 26.2120144
9   84  B   19.67310555 1.993071082 9.08442779
9   65  B   0.475983889 16.72261394 17.17122898
10  40  B   9.553130945 17.88616649 22.17570401
10  40  B   19.70487161 5.898428653 11.25844279
1   19  C   20.47792809 9.344376127 7.855311112
1   59  C   14.59141273 8.090534362 19.6972446
2   19  C   6.624345353 0.192145343 26.31356322
2   67  C   24.483236   6.718856437 25.75609679
3   67  C   27.6408808  24.91014602 25.90758755
3   30  C   26.52738124 10.78363589 4.873602089
4   14  C   3.776964641 21.16561036 24.03153234
4   46  C   16.53719818 23.86634958 25.61504006
5   48  C   5.591317152 25.17616679 24.30522374
5   16  C   23.85069753 23.12154586 0.781450997
6   58  C   28.1357636  15.89359176 0.567406646
6   28  C   0.708229201 12.20641988 0.309303591
7   17  C   4.319991082 21.29233667 3.516184987
7   8   C   24.09490443 9.507000131 14.93472971
8   85  C   19.99606403 21.61509867 0.161222766
8   5   C   6.056082264 25.35186187 5.375641692
9   24  C   19.83904205 24.54037422 11.08571464
9   13  C   4.388769239 7.928106767 4.279531285
10  78  C   13.67598922 5.3140143   15.2710129
10  13  C   12.27642791 16.04610858 1.815260029
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Maybe even there is some groupby apply logic which could assist in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `fillna()` row-wise in `apply()`, then fill with a random sample from the dataframe filtered by your conditions:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(df[(df['menu'] == row['menu']) & (df['id'] != row['id'])].dropna().sample(n=1).iloc[0]), axis=1)
```